# TSQL: FOR XML PATH('') Failing To Group

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, for-xml-path

I'm trying to group column values by a specific column using `FOR XML PATH('')` in TSQL.  This is the result in both cases (note that the without XML code - ie: `SELECT * FROM @xml` - is the same as the with XML code):

```
Class          |     Animals
=================================
Asteroidea     |     Starfish
Mammalia       |     Dog
Mammalia       |     Cat
Mammalia       |     Coyote
Reptilia       |     Crocodile
Reptilia       |     Lizard
```

According to [this article](http://www.mahipalreddy.com/blog/?p=79) and [this article](http://sqlandme.com/2011/04/27/tsql-concatenate-rows-using-for-xml-path/) (note that the second article leaves out the `GROUP BY`, which I'm unsure how the author managed to pull this off without it - I've tried and it only generates all the values), the syntax should be as shown below this:

```
DECLARE @xml TABLE(
    Animal VARCHAR(50),
    Class VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @xml
VALUES ('Dog','Mammalia')
    , ('Cat','Mammalia')
    , ('Coyote','Mammalia')
    , ('Starfish','Asteroidea')
    , ('Crocodile','Reptilia')
    , ('Lizard','Reptilia')

SELECT x1.Class
    , STUFF((SELECT ',' + x2.Animal AS [text()] 
    FROM @xml x2 
    WHERE x1.Animal = x2.Animal 
    ORDER BY x2.Animal 
    FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'' ) AS "Animals"
FROM @xml x1
GROUP BY Class
```

After a few hours, between these examples and the above code, I fail to see where I'm wrong on syntax, but I'm receiving the error "Column '@xml.Animal' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."  Note that if I leave off the GROUP BY clause, it still doesn't produce the values in the appropriate manner.  Another set of eyes would be useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you have your `WHERE` clause using the wrong column, you want to use `Class` not `Animal`:

```
SELECT x1.Class
    , STUFF((SELECT ',' + x2.Animal AS [text()] 
    FROM @xml x2 
    WHERE x1.Class = x2.Class 
    ORDER BY x2.Animal 
    FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'' ) AS "Animals"
FROM @xml x1
GROUP BY Class
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/12109). The result is:

```
|      CLASS |          ANIMALS |
---------------------------------
| Asteroidea |         Starfish |
|   Mammalia |   Cat,Coyote,Dog |
|   Reptilia | Crocodile,Lizard |
```