# SQL Server SSRS Multiple lookup values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I have a huge set of data. Some pf the data has multiple values, kinda looking like this:

```
Column 1    Column 2
A           1
A           10
A           1E
B           2F
B           1BH
C           WBH
D           3X
D           2
D           1
D           10
D           11
```

I would like to select the unique values in `Column 1` and display all relevant values of `Column 2` in as string separated by comma (using SSRS). i.e.

```
Column 1    Column 2
A           01, 10, 1E
B           2F, 1BH
C           WBH
D           02, 01, 10, 11
```

In addition, any value in `Column 1` that is less than 10, I would like it to be preceded by a zero.

I know I can use `SELECT DISTINCT` to get all unique values of `Column 1`. But I am unsure how to go around `Column 2`?

With regards to having a zero preceding numbers less than 10, I can do this:

```
SELECT RIGHT('0' + convert(varchar(2), value()), 2)
```

I am unsure how to put it all together to get the result I want.

Thank you.

Comment: Similar questions have been asked before. Check out the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843649/tsql-for-xml-path-failing-to-group) for inspiration.

Comment: what you are looking for is STUFF FOR XML in SQL..  padding with 0 is easy.. just look at length, and if 1 append a 0 else leave it alone.. then do the STUFF for XML.. google it.. there are thousands of examples.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

```
DECLARE @Input TABLE
(
ProductID INT,
Price INT
)

INSERT INTO @Input VALUES (6,22), (6,35), (6,77), (6, 88), (6,55),(6,200),(7,6),(7,4),(8,5),(8,5)

;WITH CTE AS
(SELECT ProductID, MAX(Price) AS Max_Price, MIN(Price) AS Min_Price 
FROM @Input 
GROUP BY ProductID
)
SELECT ProductID, CASE WHEN Max_Price > Min_Price THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Min_Price) + ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Max_Price)
                        ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Min_Price) END AS Price_Range
FROM CTE
```

[image]